# How to convert binary data to utf8 string after dart2js

Tags: utf-8, binary, dart

I'm storing my data in the localStorage. Because I store a lot of data, I need to compress it. I do it with GZip. Everything works, but I found out that my convertion from List which the result of GZip to Utf8 is extremely slow. On 500k of data, it can take up to 5 min on a fast computer.

The problem appear mainly during the loading function.

**Load:**

```dart
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:archive/archive.dart';
import 'package:crypto/crypto.dart';

var base64 = CryptoUtils.base64StringToBytes(window.localStorage[storageName]);
var decompress = new GZipDecoder().decodeBytes(base64);
storage = JSON.decode(new Utf8Decoder().convert(decompress));
```

**Save:**

```dart
var g = JSON.encode(storage);
List<int> bz2 = new GZipEncoder().encode(new Utf8Encoder().convert(g));
window.localStorage[storageName] = CryptoUtils.bytesToBase64(bz2);
```

Am I doing something wrong? Is there other way of converting a List to a String in Dart? Also, I do both save and load, so there is no need of utf8.

I tried Ascii, but it throws error for unsupported character. I got kind of working latin1, for which a much higher performance, but I still get some unsupported character.

Comment: Which GZipDecoder you are using on browser?

Comment: I use GZipDecoder  from the import 'package:archive/archive.dart'; which is fast, the problem is with the Utf8Decoder.

Comment: I filed http://dartbug.com/22330. I'm not sure when we will have the time to look into it, though. (Feel free to remind us from time to time on the bug if nothing seems to happen).

Comment: We recently made the [UTF-8 decoding faster](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/commit/3836c70a8150bc33a695788deee346b940b40769) in common cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If UTF-8 is really the bottleneck, and you don't need it, you can just use Dart's native String encoding which is UTF-16.

```dart
var compressed = new GZipEncoder().encode(str.codeUnits);
var decompressed = new GZipDecoder().decodeBytes(compressed);
var finalStr = new String.fromCharCodes(decompressed);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just a hack and is not the best, but it works and it's giving me good performance for now:

```dart
String convertListIntToUtf8(List<int> codeUnits) {
  var endIndex = codeUnits.length;
  StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
  int i = 0;
  while (i < endIndex) {
    var c = codeUnits[i];
    if (c < 0x80) {
      buffer.write(new String.fromCharCode(c));
      i += 1;
    } else if (c < 0xE0) {
      buffer.write(new String.fromCharCode((c << 6) + codeUnits[i+1] - 0x3080));
      i += 2;
    } else if (c < 0xF0) {
      buffer.write(new String.fromCharCode((c << 12) + (codeUnits[i+1] << 6) + codeUnits[i+2] - 0xE2080));
      i += 3;
    } else {
      buffer.write(new String.fromCharCode((c << 18) + (codeUnits[i+1] << 12) + (codeUnits[i+2] << 6) + codeUnits[i+3] - 0x3C82080));
      i += 4;
    }
    if (i >= endIndex) break;
  }
  return buffer.toString();
}
```